# Vue.js Binding v-model with Summernote input

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

What I'm trying to do is to bind the value of summer note textarea into a Vue Component, But that doesn't seem to work! Either I can Show Summer Note or do the Binding!!

```
<textarea v-model="text" class="form-control summernote" required rows="15"></textarea>
```

this text area is inside component and when taking out class `summernote` the input binds and saves my value in database just fine, But if I make it as `summernote` input the `bindinf` fails

Html Code :

[image]

[image]

JS code :

[image]

I just want to bind value into vue text :

[image]

Comment: Five points to Grifindor for screenshot of code, it's brilliant, thanks!

Comment: Instead of screenshot user add code here, that's help developer to resolved the issue in min time.